# how to find a selected vert's symmetrical pair on a maya mesh

Tags: python, maya

What would be the best (fastest) method to find a given vertex's symmetrical pair (ie , a vert on the left side of a mesh and its right hand side equivalent) Is it possible to use the open maya api in python for this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to check the position of every vert against every other over and over, that will be extremely slow.

A simple approach is to get a hash value - a simple comparison operation - for every vertex that is identical for two verts which are symmetrical.  Luckily tuples - NOT lists!! - are hashable.  So the algorithm would be:

1. get a position tuple for each vert
2. make a dictionary (position: vertex) for all the verts on the 'left' (or 'up' or 'back' etc) side.
3. make a second dictionary (position: vertex) for the verts on the opposite side, with the symmetry axis flipped:  if you were doing left/right axis, the left list would be

   ```
   { (x, y, z) : "pCube1.vtx[0]" }  #etc
   ```

   and the right list would be

   ```
   { (-1 * x, y, z) : "pCube1.vtx[99]" } # and so on
   ```
4. Any key which is duplicated in both dictionaries is symmetrical, so you need to collect the keys which show up in both and then get the verts from each side they represent:

   ```
   duplicates = [j for j in leftDictionary if j in rightDictionary]
   pairs = [leftDictionary[k], rightDictionary[k] for k in keys]
   ```

This won't be super fast on big meshes but it should do the trick.

The one place it may have issues is if there are floating point discrepancies between the sides so items which are visually symmetrical may not be mathematically symmetrical.  You could modify it to match numbers withing a given tolerance by, say, quantizing the values you put into the tuples  -- the easy way would be to blow them up by some factor, say 1000, and then turn them into integers.  The raw method errs on the side of missing some things which look symmetrical but aren't exactly, the quantized method may collapse multiple matches if they are too close.  I'd stick with the raw data unless it's failing to do what you need.

Comment: Or just use a spatially sorted list it's then easy to accept small deviations. It would then be a N log N operation. The problem with discretisation is what if the dual is located just on the other side of a discrete border.

Comment: By the way why do your engineers get nervous about spheres?